# how do you create a simple variable in racket?

Tags: racket

i would like to see how long it took for racket to generate this list.

> (current-inexact-milliseconds)
>   (length (list "hop" "skip" "jump"))
>   (current-inexact-milliseconds)

how do i make these times varibles in seconds so i can substract them?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket

(define time1 (current-inexact-milliseconds))
(length (list "hop" "skip" "jump"))
(define time2 (current-inexact-milliseconds))
(- time2 time1)
```

Comment: Note that `(time (length (list "hop" "skip" "jump")))` is the standard way of timing a single expression.

Comment: Also it's usually good to do `(for ([i 3]) (collect-garbage))` immediately before the timing, to get a "clean slate". Otherwise previous unrelated evaluations' allocations might be GCd and inflate the time. (Yeah the `3` is a magic number but that's the conventional wisdom AFAICT.)

Answer (score 1):

Save the initial time in a variable using `let`:

```
(let ((start (current-inexact-milliseconds))) 
  (length (list "hop" "skip" "jump")) 
  (- (current-inexact-milliseconds) start))
```